# Is there a way to dynamically define and register new Dgraphs in Endeca

Tags: endeca

As far as my knowledge of Endeca goes, any time you want to add a new dgraph definition in your Endeca configuration, you have to run `initializeServices.sh` to set the updated configuration on EAC.

I was wondering if there is any way I can do that without running `initalizeServices.sh` (since it does a lot more than just update the list of Dgraph registered in EAC, and I want to prevent that).

I found the command `./runcommand.sh --update-definition` allows you to do configuration changes to a Dgraph, which has already been registered with EAC, but if I add a new dgraph in config and run the command it fails with below error:

```
[11.17.16 16:00:07] INFO: Setting definition for host 'MDEXLiveHost2'.
[11.17.16 16:00:07] SEVERE: Caught an exception while checking provisioning
Caused by com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.exception.EacCommunicationException
com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.host.Host setDefinition - Caught exception while setting host definition.
Caused by com.endeca.eac.client.ProvisioningFault
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl newInstance0 - null
```

I can't find any detailed logs of this error being generated anywhere in PlatformServices logs to further debug.

I could, however see in request log that `/eac/ProvisioningService` gave a HTTP code of `500`, which leads me to believe that the script is trying to find current configuration of `MDEXLiveHost2` and is unable to find it.

EDITED TO ADD Configuration for:

New host:

`<host id="MDEXLiveHost2" hostName="${mdexLive.host2}" port="${mdexLive.eac.port}" useSsl="false" />`

New Dgraph:

```
<dgraph id="DgraphLive2" host-id="MDEXLiveHost2" port="${dgraphLive1.port}"
      post-startup-script="LiveDgraphPostStartup">
    <properties>
        <property name="restartGroup" value="A" />
        <property name="updateGroup" value="a" />
        <property name="DgraphContentGroup" value="Live" />
    </properties>
    <log-dir>./logs/dgraphs/DgraphLive</log-dir>
    <input-dir>./data/dgraphs/DgraphLive/dgraph_input</input-dir>
    <update-dir>./data/dgraphs/DgraphLive/dgraph_input/updates</update-dir>
</dgraph>
```

EDITED TO ADD errors after manually adding host using `eaccmd.sh`

Host definition file:

```
<host host-id="MDEXLiveHost2" host-name="172.18.0.7" port="9999" useSsl="false"/>
```

The host is added successfully (validated via `describe-app`)

`$./eaccmd.sh describe-app --app myapp | grep MDEXLiveHost2
<host host-name="172.18.0.7" port="9999" host-id="MDEXLiveHost2" useSsl="false">`

But, running any command I get this error:

```
[11.18.16 11:00:58] INFO: Updating provisioning for host 'MDEXLiveHost2'.
[11.18.16 11:00:58] INFO: Host name of host 'MDEXLiveHost2' has changed from 172.18.0.7 to 172.18.0.7 . Components on this host will be re-provisioned.
[11.18.16 11:00:58] INFO: Updating definition for host 'MDEXLiveHost2'.
[11.18.16 11:00:58] SEVERE: Caught an exception while checking provisioning.

Caused by com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.exception.EacCommunicationException
com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.host.Host updateEacDefinition - Caught exception while updating host definition.
Caused by com.endeca.eac.client.ProvisioningFault
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl newInstance0 - null
```

If only this error could be made more verbose, that might give some help.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to run `initializeServices.sh` for every configuration change you make. When you execute other scripts in the `control` folder, they first check if there are any configuration changes and apply these changes.

As far as the error is concerned, I suspect you either didn't specify the `MDEXLiveHost2` in your `LiveDGraphCluster.xml` or the host that you did specify is not reachable. Verify your configuration.

Lastly your approach to dynamically add more `DGraphs` into the cluster is not standard practice. When you configure your environment you should do a load test using `ENEPerf` to simulate the load and then create as many `DGraphs` and hosts as required. If you are adding more hosts and `DGraphs` dynamically, you also need to ensure that you add them, dynamically, into your load balancer configuration as well.

Comment: Thanks for response. I did add the definition for new host (I'll add the configuration as an edit on original post)
As for the suggestion of adding new dgraphs to load-balancer, that part is already achieved, only if I could add the dgraphs properly first :)

Comment: I assume `mdexLive.host2` is a separate machine that already has `MDEX` and `PlatformServices` installed when you try to add it dynamically into the cluster? Have you tried to execute a `runcommand.sh  DgraphLive2 stop` and `runcommand.sh  DgraphLive2 start` to see if it establishes connectivity that way?

Comment: Sorry, no dice. I got the exact same error.
In the meantime, I found `eaccmd.sh` and tried `./eaccmd.sh describe-app --app myapp` and there isn't any definition for MDEXLiveHost2.  So I tried to add this host using `eaccmd.sh` and got a different error (will add as an edit again)

Answer (score 0):

My first guess was that maybe the mdex host 2 didn't have Platform services/Mdex installed and Platform services running but it may be that the port you specified is incorrect.

```
<host host-id="MDEXLiveHost2" host-name="172.18.0.7" port="9999" useSsl="false"/>
```

Is your eac port 9999 and not 8888 (OOB value)? If it is 9999 on your ITL server, you want to make sure that it is also set to 9999 on your new Dgraph server.